# Elixir regex groups and ?-mark

Tags: regex, elixir, pcre

I'm trying to use the following regex

```
~r/(?<cmd>.*)(:(?<args>.*))?/
```

to get the following behaviour

```
"COMMAND:ARGS" => %{cmd: "COMMAND", args: "ARGS"}
"COMMAND" => %{cmd: "COMMAND", args: nil}
```

But all I get is

```
iex(66)> Regex.named_captures(~r/(?<cmd>.*)(:(?<args>.*))?/, "COMMAND:ARG")
%{"args" => "", "cmd" => "COMMAND:ARG"}
iex(67)> Regex.named_captures(~r/(?<cmd>.*)(:(?<args>.*))?/, "COMMAND")       
%{"args" => "", "cmd" => "COMMAND"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the original string?

Comment: I want it to parse two types of strings: "COMMAND:ARG" and "COMMAND".

Comment: Oh I understand now. Does `(?<cmd>[^:]+)(?::(?<args>.*))?` work for you?

Comment: Yeeeeees! Thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/6Jl2jV/1)

```
(?<cmd>[^:]+)(?::(?<args>.*))?
(?<cmd>[^:\n]+)(?::(?<args>.*))?   # for multiline content
```

- `(?<cmd>[^:\n]+)` Capture any character except `:` or `\n` (in the second version) into capture group named `cmd`
- `(?::(?<args>.*))?` Optionally match the following

  - `:` Match this literally
  - `(?<args>.*)` Capture the rest of the line into capture group named `args`

Results:

```
Match 1
    Full match      0-12    `COMMAND:ARGS`
    Group `cmd`     0-7     `COMMAND`
    Group `args`    8-12    `ARGS`
Match 2
    Full match      13-20   `COMMAND`
    Group `cmd`     13-20   `COMMAND`
```